# Trigger Event in behind code when click on Dynamically added button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling, dynamically-generated

I am trying to call `btn_Click` from the dynamically added button using `HtmlTextWriter`. But it will not trigger. I am unable to add event handler in code behind to the button as it is not a ASP.NET button.

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         WindowJavaScript.Alert("halo");
    }

protected void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some checking hee to determine whether user is admin or not.
    if(isAdmin)
    {
         writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "nav navbar-nav navbar-right");
         writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);
         writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);

         writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "navbar-brand");
         writer.AddAttribute("runat", "server");
         writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "admin_B");
         writer.AddAttribute("onserverclick", "btn_Click");
         writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);

         writer.Write("Admin");
         writer.RenderEndTag();
         writer.RenderEndTag();
         writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the event method where you try to do this?

Comment: Can you add this lines of code in on init event? `protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) { }`
Also, you are constrainted to use HtmlTextWritter?

Comment: It doesn't work in Page_Init. Any recommended method instead of HtmlTextWriter?

Comment: I posted an answer with an recommended alternative, please also read the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to translate your code to map attributes to a button i noticed that you have `writer.AddAttribute("onserverclick", "btn_Click")` and you should have `writer.AddAttribute("onclick", "btn_Click")`.

Also you can add a button dynamically in your page by appending it to another control from the page.

```
protected void PageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //some checking hee to determine whether user is admin or not.
        if (isAdmin)
        {
            var btnAdmin = new Button();
            btnAdmin.Click += btn_Click;
            btnAdmin.Text = "Admin";
            btnAdmin.ID = "admin_B";

            otherControl.Controls.Add(btnAdmin); // you need to create otherControl on page
        }
}
```